# Pipe commands call the signal function twice

Tags: c++, shell, pipe, signals

I'm trying to create a basic shell that supports piping. So I wrote the following code:

```
int file_descriptor[2];
if (pipe(file_descriptor) == -1) {
    perror("error: pipe failed");
    return;
}

int command_pid1 = fork();
if (command_pid1 < 0) {
    perror("error: fork failed");
    return;
}

if (command_pid1 > 0) {
    // Parent process
    if (waitpid(command_pid1, NULL, 0) < 0) {
        perror("error: waitpid failed");
    }

    int command_pid2 = fork();
    if (command_pid2 < 0) {
        perror("error: fork failed");
        return;
    }

    if (command_pid2 > 0) {
        // Parent process
        close(file_descriptor[0]);
        close(file_descriptor[1]);
        waitpid(command_pid2 , NULL, 0);
        return;
    }

    if (command_pid2 == 0) {
        // Child process
        dup2(file_descriptor[0],STDIN_FILENO);
        close(file_descriptor[0]);
        close(file_descriptor[1]);
        instance.execute(second_command);
        exit(0);
    }
}

if (command_pid1 == 0) {
    // Child process
    if (pipe_err) {
        dup2(file_descriptor[1], STDERR_FILENO);
    } else {
        dup2(file_descriptor[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    }

    close(file_descriptor[0]);
    close(file_descriptor[1]);
    instance.execute(first_command);
    exit(0);
}
```

I want to support input like `sleep 1 | sleep 10` where `sleep 1` is `first_command` and `sleep 2` is the `second_command`. I also want to support signals.
My code works ok until I'm trying to press `Ctrl+C` while the pipe is running. The way I set the handler:

```
signal(SIGINT, ctrlCHandler);
```

In the `ctrlCHandler` I print that the user clicked `Ctrl+C`.

So when I use `Ctrl+C` while `sleep 1 | sleep 10` is being ran, It prints `Pressed Ctrl+C` twice and it should print only once. I can't seem to figure out way to fix it so it will print only once. How should I handle the signals?

Comment: The shown code in this question does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre], and because of that it is unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: *" when I use `Ctrl+C` while `sleep 1 | sleep 10` is being ran"* -- does it matter which command is active? I.e. does using `Ctrl+C` during the first second (first command) have the same result as during the last ten seconds (second command)?

Comment: When you hit Ctrl+C, all processes in the foreground process group receive `SIGINT`.